# Change of variable in a probability density function

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

In Bishop's *Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning*, I'm confused by the section on the change of variable of a probability density function. The paragraph concerned is bellow.

[image]

So, given a change of variable such as $x=g(y)$, the pdf of $y$ is defined as: $$p_y(y)=p_x(g(y))|g'(y)|$$

**How do we get here ?** Also, but that may be obvious after an answer to the first question, in equation 1.27, why do we have the absolute value of $\frac{dx}{dy}$ ?

Comment: They explicitly state that $p(x)$ must be $\geqslant 0$ in other words that the probabilities must be nonnegative. Since the change in x with respect to the change in y can be negative, thereby resulting in a negative probability after multiplication, the derivative must be made positive, so they use the absolute value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $P(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xp(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$ is the probability that the variable will be less than $x$. Thus, if $g$ is a monotonically increasing function, $P(g(x))$ is the probability that the variable will be less than $g(x)$.

By the chain rule, the probability density of $P(g(x))$ is $P'(g(x))g'(x)=p(g(x))\left|g'(x)\right|$.

If $g$ is monotonically decreasing, then $P(g(x))$ is the probability that the variable will be greater than $g(x)$.

By the chain rule, the probability density of $P(g(x))$ is $-P'(g(x))g'(x)=p(g(x))\left|g'(x)\right|$.

The situation is more complicated if $g$ is not monotonic; we need to sum the expressions above for all the points where $g(x)$ is a certain value.

Comment: Many thanks, I didn't think of using the cumulative distribution function... I will need some time to get my head around this though.

Comment: How do you say $P'(g(x))g'(x) = p(g(x))|g'(x)|$? I do not understand where the absolute value comes from.

Comment: @Sam: did you read the part about $g$ being monotonically increasing/decreasing?

Comment: I read it, but I realized just now the obvious implication. Thanks!