# Transformation in probability density function due to change in variable (Many to One case).

Tags: probability, probability-theory, machine-learning, jacobian

First, Let me quote a paragraph from "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning"-Bishop:

> Under a nonlinear change of variable, a probability density transforms differently
>   from a simple function, due to the Jacobian factor. For instance, if we consider
>   a change of variables x = g(y), then a function f(x) becomes $\tilde{f}(y) = f(g(y))$.
>   Now consider a probability density $p_x(x)$ that corresponds to a density $p_y(y)$ with
>   respect to the new variable y, where the suffices denote the fact that $p_x(x)$ and $p_y(y)$
>   are different densities. Observations falling in the range (x, x + δx) will, for small
>   values of δx, be transformed into the range (y, y + δy) where ,
>   and hence $p_y(y) = p_x(g(y)) |g'(y)|$ .

I have two questions here:

1. I can clearly understand the equation ( $p_x(x)δx \simeq p_y(y)δy$ ) for the case when x=g(y) is one to one function. Is there any explaination why this would also hold for a one to many function ($g(x)$)? For example, consider $x = g(y) = sin(y/10000000)$. Which means, $Y \epsilon (0,0+\delta{y})$ maps to $X \epsilon (0,0+\delta{x})$. Isn't here $p_x(x)δx \gt p_y(y)δy $
2. And can comeone explain how does this $|g'(x)|$ come from in the last equation?

PS: The second question has already been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1424388/change-of-variable-in-a-probability-density-function), but I still didnt understand how does that negative sign come from chain rule, in montonically decreasing case (in the answer).